# Can we receive Raw push notification if WP 8.1 app is closed?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 App,in which I am capable of receiving a **raw** push notification using WNS.

I discovered following two scenarios: 
1)Notification delivery event,used when app is running i.e. in foreground
2)Background task triggered by the raw notification,used when app is not running .

I am able to receive Push notification when application is in foreground and when not running(in background).To receive notification in background I used background task.

Means I can receive notification in these scenarios:
1)when app is in foreground
2)when app is in background

I am able to get notification when app is in background as I registered background task.
Will that background task work when app is not in memory?
I am not able to receive notification when application is **closed**.

My question is:**Can I be able to get that raw push notification when my app is closed and I registered with background task?**

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to get the raw push notification when your Windows Phone XAML or Silverlight 8.1 app is closed and you've registered a `PushNotificationTrigger`.  See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d for a sample that does this (it's a universal app that works across windows\window phone 8.1).

One common issue for `PushNotificationTrigger` not firing is if you have not called `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()` and validated its return value before registering your background task.  This is required for both Windows and Windows Phone when using `PushNotificationTrigger` (note: all triggers requires this call for Windows Phone unlike Windows).

Comment: How to unregister that push notification. I got success on receiving raw notifications and show toasts. But I still receive raw notifications even if I unregister that BackgroundTask. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think, Windows Azure Mobile Services can do that. If you  want  to try this is the link. Windows Azure is trial for 90 days.

[Windows Azure Free Trial 90 Days. Click to Register.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/)

**Here is the Mobile Services Tutorials.**

[Windows Azure Mobile Services .Net Backend. Tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/)

[Windows Azure Mobile Services Javascript Backend. Tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-get-started/)

Comment: The trials time has been reduced to one month (30 days)